# How do I use regex to get replace certain characters in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, suse

I am new to bash so I don't much about regex syntax in bash. I am trying to get rid the `___.xml` part from an array of file paths and trying to store it in a temporary variable. I will then `cat` the temporary variable. The reason why is because I will be using the array in another section. So far I have this code (with an error of course) which doesn't output anything:

```
files=()
files+=/server/1.0/hostname/filename.xml
files+=/server/1.0/hostname/another_file.xml

for (( i = 0 ; i<${#files[@]} ; i++ )); do
    cat ${files[$i]} 2> /dev/null
done
```

What I want to do is create a `temp` var inside the for loop so it looks something like this:

```
files=()
files+=/server/1.0/hostname/filename.xml
files+=/server/1.0/hostname/another_file.xml

for (( i = 0 ; i<${#files[@]} ; i++ )); do
    temp=`echo ${files[$i]} | ADD REGEX HERE`
    cat $temp 2> /dev/null
done
```

Is there a way to do so? Thanks!

Comment: What is the problem? And what do you want in `ADD REGEX HERE`?

Comment: @anubhava The problem is that in the first segment code there is no output

Comment: @anubhava I want to add a regular expression or something of its equivalence in the `ADD REGEX HERE` section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have syntax issue in BASH array handling. Try this:

```
files=()
files+=(/server/1.0/hostname/filename.xml)
files+=(/server/1.0/hostname/another_file.xml)

for f in "${files[@]}"; do
    cat "$f" 2>/dev/null
done
```

Comment: no syntax issues, the first segment of code worked when i rebooted the computer. this segment also works.

Answer (score 1):

This will print the basename of the file. I think thats what you were asking for ?

```
#!/bin/bash

files=()
files+=(/server/1.0/hostname/filename.xml)
files+=(/server/1.0/hostname/another_file.xml)

for f in "${files[@]}"; do
    echo ${f##*/}
done
```